# canvas Elements goes invisible after clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to to write undo/Redo functionality on canvas . i am using fabric-js to draw Objects . undo ?Redo is working fine but the problem is  after calling undo/redo function if i click on canvas Elements goes Invisible. i tried canvas.renderAll() still i am getting problem.

Steps for Undo::

1. Before Element Drawn i am saving `canvas.toDataURl()` in an variable Array.

   2.When Undo Button is clicked i am using clear method of fabric to clear canvas and then getting variable Array to Draw on canvas using Previous `toDataUrl() .

Code ::

```
     function undoDrawOnCanvas() {
        console.log('inside undodrawn');
        // If we have some restore points
        if (restorePoints.length > 0) {
            // Create a new Image object

            var oImg = new Image();
            // When the image object is fully loaded in the memory...
            oImg.onload = function() {

                //Saving point for Redo
                c_redo=document.getElementById("design_text").toDataURL("image/png");

                canvas.clear();

                // Get the canvas context
                var canvasContext = document.getElementById("design_text").getContext("2d");
                // and draw the image (restore point) on the canvas. That would overwrite anything
                // already drawn on the canvas, which will basically restore it to a previous point.
                canvasContext.drawImage(oImg, 0, 0);
            }
            // The source of the image, is the last restoration point
            oImg.src = restorePoints.pop();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the canvas still exist ? If yes, is it put in the background, or zero-sized ?

Comment: @Cedric canvas still exists , i just want to draw restorePoint() i.e.toDataUrl() on it

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764008/if-canvas-clicked-drawing-on-canvas-going-invisible#comment27663109_18764008
fabric.js draws only elements that are stored in canvas._objects. You draw a image with native canvas methods => on every mouseUp event canvas is cleared an object (canvas._objects) are rerenderd.

Comment: @Kienz hey i went through https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/201 in Github. i am trying to do layer managament by canvas.sendBackwards() , can plz tell how can i change z-index using canvas.getObjects()

Comment: @Kienz   ??? =canvas.getObjects().indexOf(hw[object_id])+1;   i want to assigned incread index value but how?

Comment: Not sure what you want. There are the following methods to change "z-index":
canvas.sendBackwards(obj), canvas.sendToBack(obj), canvas.bringForward(obj), canvas.bringToFront(obj) and canvas.moveTo(obj, index). All that methods can also be used direct on objects: eg. obj.sendBackwards().

Comment: @kienz yes , canvas.object gives list of all objects on canvas ,i just want to print list of their position . is there any function like "canvas.getObject().get() "   to get text or name of object?

Comment: canvas.forEachObject(function(o, i) {
  console.log(o.get('type'), i);
}
fabric.Objects has no name property. But you can add it by your own:
obj.set('name', 'obj1');
Maybe you can show small jsfiddle testcase.