# If canvas clicked Drawing on canvas going invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fabricjs

Below function i am using to draw line randomly on canvas .i have used fabricjs to draw other Elements also .

Problem ::

Problem is when After drawing i clicked on canvas , all Elements drawn Goes Invisible .

```
  function drawOnCanvas() {
            // We want to store the state of the canvas, before we apply the change on it. That way we can
            // revert back to the state before the canvas was changed.
            saveRestorePoint();
            console.log('inside draw on canvas');
            var canvasContext = document.getElementById("design_text").getContext("2d");

            // Choose random coordinates for start and end point of the line we will drive
            var xFrom = getRandomInt(0, canvasContext.canvas.width);
            var yFrom = getRandomInt(0, canvasContext.canvas.height);
            var xTo = getRandomInt(0, canvasContext.canvas.width);
            var yTo = getRandomInt(0, canvasContext.canvas.height);

            // .save() and .restore() only save and restore the fill style of the canvas context.
            // They are not relevant to the canvas drawing state.
            canvasContext.save();
            // We choose a random color for our line
            canvasContext.strokeStyle = randomColor();
            // and a random width
            canvasContext.lineWidth = getRandomInt(1, 4);

            // It is important to .beginPath() and .closePath(), otherwise you will end up with artifacts
            canvasContext.beginPath();
            // We go to the starting position of the line
            canvasContext.moveTo(xFrom, yFrom);
            // and draw the line to its end position
            canvasContext.lineTo(xTo, yTo);
            // then we color it
            canvasContext.stroke();
            // and close the shape
            canvasContext.closePath();

            // We restore the original fill state (color, width, etc...) of the canvas
            canvasContext.restore();
        }

        /*** Those are some helper functions, not directly related to the Canvas ***/

        // Get a random number in a range (from, to)
        function getRandomInt(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }

        // Returns a random hex number
        function randomColor() {
            var rint = Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random());
            return ('#0' + rint.toString(16)).replace(/^#0([0-9a-f]{6})$/i, '#$1');
        }
```

Comment: fabric.js clears the context before drawing elements (method renderAll). canvas.renderAll() is called in mouseUp event. You can draw native canvas elements in after:render event.